# How to iterate over an Photos.app album (or a container) using Javascript?

Tags: photos, javascript, album

How can I iterate over the media items of an album in Photos.app?

By copying and editing online code, I got this far:

```
for (const album of Application("Photos").albums()) {
    console.log("Processing album '" + album.name() + "'")
    for (var idx in album) {
        console.log(idx)
     } 
}
```

However, this doesn't work.  I know that each album in `Application("Photos").albums()` is a container, but I couldn't find an example how to iterate over its content using javascript.
In other code, I have already created a javascript `Map` where each key is the filename(+size+ratio) and it contains lists of duplicates (all but one to be deleted).
Iterating through the albums, I want to extract the properties of the media items to check whether an item is to be deleted and if yes, replace them with the non-deleted duplicates.

Any help or pointers to examples greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using Node or some other scripting environment? Please tell us how you are invoking this code plus what does `console.log(Application("Photos"))` output?

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am working directly in apple's ScriptEditor.app.  I just checked `console.log(Application("Photos"))` which results in `Error -2700: Script error.`.   However, I think I found the answer to my original question, which I will post in a minute...

Comment: Is `console.log()` valid inside of Script Editor? Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try "Show Log" (or Cmd-3) from the View menu in the menu bar.  Then there should be an area below the the code with four tabs "Result", "Messages", "Events", "Replies".  Choose "Messages".  Next run your script, e.g. `console.log("Hello world")`.  Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471889/jxa-get-containers-of-an-element I found out, how to do it:

```
for (const album of Application("Photos").albums()) {
    console.log("Processing album '" + album.name() + "'")
    for (var photo of album.mediaItems()) {
        console.log(photo.filename())
    }
}
```

So, the correct way to do it is to iterate over the `album.mediatItems()` with `for (var ... of ...) { ... }`.